# Target Invocation exception in Xamarin Forms Android when using french culture with font attributes

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I used the labels in my xamarin page and set **FontAttributes** as like below code in my xaml page. By default (US culture) no issues. When i change my android device culture as french i am getting System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException. If i remove FontAttributes, it is working fine. I can't debug or get details from output window. Anyone please help on this.

My Code

```
<Label x:Name="continentLabel" FontAttributes="Bold"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

I created a simple xamarin forms project and edited the xaml file as you have posted, I also added two RESX files:AppResources.resx and AppResources.fr.resx, then I set the simulator's language setting to French. It works all right. I think you may missed something, so I post my code here:

MainPage.xaml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:App34"
             x:Class="App34.MainPage">

    <StackLayout>
        <!-- Place new controls here -->
        <Label Text="Welcome to Xamarin.Forms!" 
           HorizontalOptions="Center"
           VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
        <Label x:Name="String1" 
           FontAttributes="Bold" 
           HorizontalOptions="Center"
           VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
    </StackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace App34
{
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            String1.Text = AppResources.String1;

        }
    }
}
```